# Refreshing DevExpress.XtraGrid after adding items to list that was boun to it

Tags: c#, binding, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a `List<SomeClass>` bound to DevExpressXtraGrid like:

```
MyXtraGrid.DataSource = MyList;
```

I have some columns made in XtraGrid designer. Everything is ok and rows were shown in grid, but when I add objects to MyList grid is not refreshed and new item was not shown.

I've tried with `MyXtraGrid.Refresh()`, tried to rebind with `MyXtraGrid.DataSource = MyList`, but it didn't work.

`MyXtraGrix.MyView.PopulareColumns()` is not an option, cause I don't wont all fields from MyList to be show in grid, and this will earse columns I've configured with designer.

How to refresh the grid view to show object I've added ?

Answer (score 9):

Simply do this:

```
    private void BindCollection(IEnumerable collection)
    {
        // keep current index
        GridView view = MyXtraGrid.Views[0] as GridView;
        int index = 0;
        int topVisibleIndex = 0;
        if (view != null)
        {
            index = view.FocusedRowHandle;
            topVisibleIndex = view.TopRowIndex;
        }

        MyXtraGrid.BeginUpdate();
        MyXtraGrid.DataSource = collection;
        MyXtraGrid.RefreshDataSource();

        if (view != null)
        {
            view.FocusedRowHandle = index;
            view.TopRowIndex = topVisibleIndex;
        }

        MyXtraGrid.EndUpdate();
    }
```

You can also get the selected row and reselect it after the new datasource has been set.

Also note that instead of `List` you can use `BindingList<>` in order to have the grid to update itself without you having to write a single line of code. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [GridControl.RefreshDataSource Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_RefreshDataSourcetopic) as i am using with my collection data Source is List of some class and it contain list of another class to create master view details.

```
GridControl scheduleGrid = sender as GridControl;
MyXtraGrid.DataSource = collection;
scheduleGrid.RefreshDataSource();
```

> If you make changes to a IList (outside of the grid) I believe you
>   would then have to call the RefreshDatasource method, and IList
>   doesn't do change notifications. [RefreshDataSource Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_RefreshDataSourcetopic)
>
> I believe that you should inherit from [IBindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx) if you want
>   it all to mesh together by itself. otherwise I do believe the
>   RefreshDatasource should work.

Reference:
[Refreshing Grid When Using Custom Enumerator](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q147873.aspx)
[How to keep unchanged scroll position when refreshing grid data_](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q246526.aspx)
[Filtering the Object DataSource](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/81844.aspx)